# Query changes collation language of mssql server

Tags: sql-server

is there any query that changes collation language not only database but also mssql server So that databases will be created in new collation language? Or do I have to establish database again?

Comment: A simple google search finds this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation

Comment: Notes - every NEW database begins by copying the model database. A database does not have a collation - it has a **DEFAULT** colllation that is used when a string-based column is created that does not specify a collation. Changing the default collation of a database will NOT change the collation of any existing column. Before you attempt anything, make absolutely sure that you have backups of anything important.

Comment: >>>A database does not have a collation<<< It's wrong. As there is SERVER collation, there is also DATABASE collation. And string COLUMN collation. There is no TABLE collation, but "database collation" is the legitim terminology

Comment: ...And the DEFAULT collation for a string column is DATABASE collation.

Comment: @sepupic Nope - and your pedantic comments are not helpful. Again - a database has a default collation setting which only applies to columns created without a specific collation. It is a **DEFAULT** setting. And changing it does not affect any existing columns - which is the far more important point to make for OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the link above is correct, I think it need some comments.

In order to change `SERVER COLLATION` you should rebuild `system databases`, and this means that after rebuild your instance will have only empty `system databases`.

All the information about databases previously attached to the instance will be lost. Of course you can first `detach` all the `user databases` and than `re-attach` them, or `restore` all the user databases from `backups`, but all your `logins` and `linked servers` will be lost.

You'll also find your `msdb` empty, so all your `jobs`, `backup/restore history` will be lost.

At this point may be you find it easier to re-install `SQL Server` with the correct `collation` since the result will be pretty the same: an instance with the correct `collation` and only empty `system databases` attached to it.

P.S. If you have already some databases with `collation A` and you change the server collation to `collation B`, after databases `restore`/`re-attach` they will preserve `collation A`. And some code using `temporary tables` may be break after this, it will fail with the errors "Could not resolve collation conflict"

Comment: Thank you @sepupic. I established ms sql server again. There wasn't so many tables in it.